# Class does not draw on the canvas

Tags: android

Why does this AI class doesn't draw to the canvas?

```
package com.dragon.game;

import android.graphics.*;
import com.dragon.game.Game.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AI {
    public static Bitmap a;
    int x, y, dirX, dirY;
    int width, height;
    long start, stop;
    boolean fg = true;
    SurView ov;
    Random r = new Random();

    public AI(SurView surView, Bitmap ai){
        a = ai;
        ov = surView;
        width = a.getWidth();
        height = a.getHeight();
        x = Remote.wt / 4;
        y = Remote.wt / 4;
    }

    public void update(){
        x++;
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        if(fg){
            x = Remote.wt / 4;
            y = Remote.wt / 4;
            fg = false;
        }

        update();
        Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
        Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + Remote.pw, y + Remote.pw);
        canvas.drawBitmap(a, src, dst, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea¿

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have initialized Bitmap a inside Public AI method and then you are using it inside onDraw method , you cannot do this , either you have to initialize it globally or you have to give a reference to it

Comment: its upto your game logic if you are good at programming , create an algorithm for it

Comment: I dont know whats wrong, it wotked like this for my player class. Can you pls help me out a bit here

Comment: Does anybody know this?

Comment: Does someone know this? Can you pls give am example of what i should do?

Comment: I reckon you should refer to this article  , It might help you out              http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/the-abcs-of-android-game-development-prepare-the-canvas/